# FATAL EXCEPTION: main... android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file...Error inflating class

Tags: android, exception, runtimeexception, inflate-exception

I am using a library which includes a cardview library. The project was working fine and then I added another module via my Gradle Settings file and now neither modules work. Here is the exception I get when I run the project using the main module which includes the cardview library:

```
01-30 09:12:30.919 12792-12792/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4be7648)
01-30 09:12:30.919 12792-12792/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{keepchange.com.healthyChange/com.cv.ui.V1MenuActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.cv.ui.widget.CollectionView
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.cv.ui.widget.CollectionView
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                       at com.cv.fragment.NativeDashFragment.onCreateView(NativeDashFragment.java:106)
                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                       at com.cv.fragment.NativeDashFragment.onCreateView(NativeDashFragment.java:106) 
                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695) 
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885) 
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 
                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682) 
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: keepchange.com.healthyChange.R$styleable
                                                       at com.cv.ui.widget.CollectionView.<init>(CollectionView.java:71)
                                                       at com.cv.ui.widget.CollectionView.<init>(CollectionView.java:58)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                       at com.cv.fragment.NativeDashFragment.onCreateView(NativeDashFragment.java:106) 
                                                       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695) 
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885) 
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 
                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682) 
                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the layout file from the main module the exception refers to:

```
<LinearLayout    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cv.fragment.NativeDashFragment"

    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    >

    <com.cv.ui.widget.CollectionView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.cv.fragment.NativeDashFragment"
    xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menu_collection_vew"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/menu_hz_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/menu_hz_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    iosched:internalPadding="4dp"
    />

    <include layout="@layout/fab_menu"/>

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Gradle Settings file from the project:

```
include ':keepchange:appmarkmine',':keepchange:healthyChange',':materialcontentoverflow', ':Scroll_library', ':Fab_library', ':Floating_M_library', ':lib-rec-v', ':library-core', ':library-cards', ':BtmShtlibrary', ':slideUpLib'
```

Comment: You're missing a class... `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: keepchange.com.healthyChange.R$styleable`

Comment: @dbo do you get the ans?